Creating a new list from the existing one
I have a python list as seen
base-list
['Year Built 2016', 'Floor 7', 'Year Built 2019', 'Floor 23', 'Year Built 2015', 'Floor 12', 'Year Built 2006', 'Floor 8', 'Year Built 2015', 'Floor 23', 'Year Built 2015', 'Floor 28', 'Year Built 2008', 'Floor 19', 'Year Built 2014', 'Floor 3', 'Year Built 2019', 'Floor 33', 'Year Built 1997', 'Floor 31', 'Year Built 2015', 'Floor 17', 'Year Built 2015', 'Floor 33', 'Year Built 1996', 'Floor 8', 'Year Built 2009', 'Floor 3', 'Year Built 2008', 'Floor 13', 'Year Built 2006', 'Floor 30', 'Year Built 2018', 'Floor 2', 'Year Built 2008', 'Floor 34', 'Year Built 2019', 'Floor 23', 'Year Built 2022', 'Floor 31', 'Year Built 2006', 'Floor 14', 'Year Built 2021', 'Floor 7', 'Year Built 2015', 'Floor 36', 'Year Built 2015', 'Floor 10', 'Year Built 2015', 'Floor 32', 'Year Built 2015', 'Floor 26', 'Year Built 2019', 'Floor 40', 'Year Built 2015', 'Floor 8', 'Year Built 2015', 'Floor 6']

from this list I wish to make new 2 seperate list. one for only 'Year built' and one for only 'Floor'. anyone can give me advince on how to do this?
I have try this method
year_built_list = [i for i in base_list if base_list[i].startwith('Y')]
*year_built_list is the new list I tried to create
but it's not working

i is the string itself, not its index. base_list[i].startwith('Y') is invalid, but i.startswith('Y') is correct.

Does this answer your question? Filter a Python list by predicate

Just a little bug in your current approach. Instead of using base_list[i].startwith('Y') use i.startswith('Year Built'), as i represents each item in your list. So your code would be like this
year_built_list = [i for i in base_list if i.startswith('Year Built')]
floor_list = [item for item in base_list if item.startswith('Floor')]

Here is a link for your reference https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp

if you're sure the base_list is alternated, you can simply skip lookups and branches
year_built_list = base_list[0::2]
floor_list = base_list[1::2]


You could use iteration_utilities.grouper like this:
from iteration_utilities import grouper
years, floors = zip(*grouper(base_list, 2))

After this assignment, years and floors will have these values:
('Year Built 2016', 'Year Built 2019', 'Year Built 2015', 'Year Built 2006', 'Year Built 2015', 'Year Built 2015', 'Year Built 2008', 'Year Built 2014', 'Year Built 2019', 'Year Built 1997', 'Year Built 2015', 'Year Built 2015', 'Year Built 1996', 'Year Built 2009', 'Year Built 2008', 'Year Built 2006', 'Year Built 2018', 'Year Built 2008', 'Year Built 2019', 'Year Built 2022', 'Year Built 2006', 'Year Built 2021', 'Year Built 2015', 'Year Built 2015', 'Year Built 2015', 'Year Built 2015', 'Year Built 2019', 'Year Built 2015', 'Year Built 2015')
('Floor 7', 'Floor 23', 'Floor 12', 'Floor 8', 'Floor 23', 'Floor 28', 'Floor 19', 'Floor 3', 'Floor 33', 'Floor 31', 'Floor 17', 'Floor 33', 'Floor 8', 'Floor 3', 'Floor 13', 'Floor 30', 'Floor 2', 'Floor 34', 'Floor 23', 'Floor 31', 'Floor 14', 'Floor 7', 'Floor 36', 'Floor 10', 'Floor 32', 'Floor 26', 'Floor 40', 'Floor 8', 'Floor 6')

These are tuples. If you really need them to be lists, then add a map call:
years, floors = map(list, zip(*grouper(base_list, 2)))

If you are running Python 3.12+, then you can use itertools.batched, which has similar functionality:
from itertools import batched
years, floors = zip(*batched(base_list, 2))


Try this once:
year_built_list = []
floor_list = []
for item in base_list:
if item.startswith('Year Built'):
    year_built_list.append(item)
elif item.startswith('Floor'):
    floor_list.append(item)

print("Year Built List:", year_built_list)
print("Floor List:", floor_list)

You can leverage on filter and lambda to achieve this as follow
  base_list = [
        'Year Built 2016', 'Floor 7', 'Year Built 2019', 'Floor 23', 'Year Built 2015', 'Floor 12',
        'Year Built 2006', 'Floor 8', 'Year Built 2015', 'Floor 23', 'Year Built 2015', 'Floor 28',
        'Year Built 2008', 'Floor 19', 'Year Built 2014', 'Floor 3', 'Year Built 2019', 'Floor 33',
        'Year Built 1997', 'Floor 31', 'Year Built 2015', 'Floor 17', 'Year Built 2015', 'Floor 33',
        'Year Built 1996', 'Floor 8', 'Year Built 2009', 'Floor 3', 'Year Built 2008', 'Floor 13',
        'Year Built 2006', 'Floor 30', 'Year Built 2018', 'Floor 2', 'Year Built 2008', 'Floor 34',
        'Year Built 2019', 'Floor 23', 'Year Built 2022', 'Floor 31', 'Year Built 2006', 'Floor 14',
        'Year Built 2021', 'Floor 7', 'Year Built 2015', 'Floor 36', 'Year Built 2015', 'Floor 10',
        'Year Built 2015', 'Floor 32', 'Year Built 2015', 'Floor 26', 'Year Built 2019', 'Floor 40',
        'Year Built 2015', 'Floor 8', 'Year Built 2015', 'Floor 6'
    ]

year_built_list = list(filter(lambda x: x.startswith('Year Built'), base_list))
floor_list = list(filter(lambda x: x.startswith('Floor'), base_list))

print("Year Built List:", year_built_list)
print("Floor List:", floor_list)

The filter is a function that requires 2 arguments,

The first is the function that returns a boolean (in our case, a lambda function).
The second is a list (in our case base-list)

The lambda uses x as each item, thus, checks if the item starts with 'Year Built', if it does, it returns True, otherwise, False.
The result is then passed to the filter which returns an iterator.
We then convert this back to a list using the list() function
See references below
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp

I already found a diffrent soluion but thank you

Assuming that the "Year built" entries would always be in even elements (starting at zero), and the "Floor" elements always in odd elements, we could just use the following two list comprehensions:
years = [lst for i, lst in enumerate(base_list) if i % 2 == 0]
floors = [lst for i, lst in enumerate(base_list) if i % 2 == 1]

If we can't rely on the indices here, we could also use a string filter approach:
years = [x for x in base_list if x.startswith('Year Built')]
floors = [x for x in base_list if x.startswith('Floor')]


base_built=['Year Built 2016', 'Floor 7', 'Year Built 2019', 'Floor 23', 'Year Built 2015', 'Floor 12', 'Year Built 2006', 'Floor 8', 'Year Built 2015', 'Floor 23', 'Year Built 2015', 'Floor 28', 'Year Built 2008', 'Floor 19', 'Year Built 2014', 'Floor 3', 'Year Built 2019', 'Floor 33', 'Year Built 1997', 'Floor 31', 'Year Built 2015', 'Floor 17', 'Year Built 2015', 'Floor 33', 'Year Built 1996', 'Floor 8', 'Year Built 2009', 'Floor 3', 'Year Built 2008', 'Floor 13', 'Year Built 2006', 'Floor 30', 'Year Built 2018', 'Floor 2', 'Year Built 2008', 'Floor 34', 'Year Built 2019', 'Floor 23', 'Year Built 2022', 'Floor 31', 'Year Built 2006', 'Floor 14', 'Year Built 2021', 'Floor 7', 'Year Built 2015', 'Floor 36', 'Year Built 2015', 'Floor 10', 'Year Built 2015', 'Floor 32', 'Year Built 2015', 'Floor 26', 'Year Built 2019', 'Floor 40', 'Year Built 2015', 'Floor 8', 'Year Built 2015', 'Floor 6']
base_years=[base_built[i] for i in range(len(base_built)) if base_built[i].startswith('Y')]
print(base_years)
Output:['Year Built 2016', 'Year Built 2019', 'Year Built 2015', 'Year Built 2006', 'Year Built 2015', 'Year Built 2015', 'Year Built 2008', 'Year Built 2014', 'Year Built 2019', 'Year Built 1997', 'Year Built 2015', 'Year Built 2015', 'Year Built 1996', 'Year Built 2009', 'Year Built 2008', 'Year Built 2006', 'Year Built 2018', 'Year Built 2008', 'Year Built 2019', 'Year Built 2022', 'Year Built 2006', 'Year Built 2021', 'Year Built 2015', 'Year Built 2015', 'Year Built 2015', 'Year Built 2015', 'Year Built 2019', 'Year Built 2015', 'Year Built 2015']

Another way

base_years=[base_built[i] for i in range(len(base_built)) if i==0 or i%2==0]
print(base_years)
Output:['Year Built 2016', 'Year Built 2019', 'Year Built 2015', 'Year Built 2006', 'Year Built 2015', 'Year Built 2015', 'Year Built 2008', 'Year Built 2014', 'Year Built 2019', 'Year Built 1997', 'Year Built 2015', 'Year Built 2015', 'Year Built 1996', 'Year Built 2009', 'Year Built 2008', 'Year Built 2006', 'Year Built 2018', 'Year Built 2008', 'Year Built 2019', 'Year Built 2022', 'Year Built 2006', 'Year Built 2021', 'Year Built 2015', 'Year Built 2015', 'Year Built 2015', 'Year Built 2015', 'Year Built 2019', 'Year Built 2015', 'Year Built 2015']
base_floors=[base_built[i] for i in range(len(base_built)) if base_built[i].startswith('F')]

Another way

base_floors=[base_built[i] for i in range(len(base_built)) if i%2!=0]
print(base_floors)
Output:['Floor 7', 'Floor 23', 'Floor 12', 'Floor 8', 'Floor 23', 'Floor 28', 'Floor 19', 'Floor 3', 'Floor 33', 'Floor 31', 'Floor 17', 'Floor 33', 'Floor 8', 'Floor 3', 'Floor 13', 'Floor 30', 'Floor 2', 'Floor 34', 'Floor 23', 'Floor 31', 'Floor 14', 'Floor 7', 'Floor 36', 'Floor 10', 'Floor 32', 'Floor 26', 'Floor 40', 'Floor 8', 'Floor 6']

I already found a diffrent soluion but thank you

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
